# Public folder no work correctly in production

Tags: node.js, express, public

I dont know why but in localhost my nodejs web work correctly and all loads good but when i setup it in my ubuntu vps, css and images not work. I already checked the dirname for the express.static().

Anyone can help me?

EDIT: Fixed and i dont know how sorry, i only waited time haha

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.